# Replace method in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to `replace` a string in javascript using `regex` but not able to do it. What I am trying is:

```
var str = [{"Contact":["{"name":"abc","address": "xyz","PhoneNumber": "08976"}", "{"name":"abc","address": "xyz","PhoneNumber": "08976"}","{"name":"abc","address": "xyz","PhoneNumber": "08976"}","{"name":"abc","address": "xyz","PhoneNumber": "08976"}"]}]
str.replace(/"\\{/g,"\\{") // replace every instance of "{ with just {
```

I want to replace all instance of `"{` with just `{` and all instance of `}"` with just `}`. How can I do 2 replacement together and where I am going wrong in 1 replacement as the replacement that I am using is not actually happening.

Comment: `str` is not a string, but an array. Didn't you forget to put `''` around the string literal on the first line?

Comment: Also, if this is meant to be a JSON string, it's usually not a good idea to parse it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant the string to be an actual string...

```
// Be sure that it's a string
var str = '[{"Contact":["{"name":"abc","address": "xyz","PhoneNumber": "08976"}", "{"name":"abc","address": "xyz","PhoneNumber": "08976"}","{"name":"abc","address": "xyz","PhoneNumber": "08976"}","{"name":"abc","address": "xyz","PhoneNumber": "08976"}"]}]';

// Assign the output to a variable and use single backslash to escape `{`. You're
// using the literal regex construct here / ... /
result = str.replace(/"(\{)|(\})"/g,"$1$2");
```

And to replace both `"{` to `{` and `}"` to `}`, you can use capture groups, backreferences and an "or" regex operator (`|`).

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U37Zp/)

Comment: Isn't that similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/21463244/548225?

Comment: What does ´$1´ and ´$2´ represent? How does `replace` replaces `"{` with `{` - there isn't any `{` to replace `"{`?

Comment: @user227666 `$1` will contain the first captured group. You get a capture group when you put something in the regex between parentheses. For instance, the first parentheses is `(\{)`, so `$1` will contain a `{`. `$2` works the same way and the second parentheses is `(\})`, so `$2` will contain `}`. When there is a match, either `"(\{)` OR `(\})"` will match. If the first matches, then `$1` will contain `{` and `$2` will be empty. If the second matches, then `$2` will contain `}` and `$1` will be empty. Thus, `$1$2` will always have one empty string, which allows for the correct replacement.

Comment: Other than some extra comments code is same and I'm sure you also realize that very well.

Comment: Are you serious? `str.replace(/"(\{)|(\})"/g, '$1$2');` vs `str.replace(/"(\{)|(\})"/g,"$1$2");`

Comment: @anubhava I'm not going to argue with you over that if that's what you're aiming for. That'll be my last reply to you if you insist on this particular subject. I'll delete the earlier comments addressed to  you here now because I consider them to be noise.

Answer (score 1):

Escape `{` with `\` once. Escaping in the replacement string is not necessary.

```
str.replace(/"\{/g,"{")
// "[{"Contact":[{"name":"abc","address": "xyz","PhoneNumber": "08976"}", {"name":"abc","address": "xyz","PhoneNumber": "08976"}",{"name":"abc","address": "xyz","PhoneNumber": "08976"}",{"name":"abc","address": "xyz","PhoneNumber": "08976"}"]}]"
```

BTW, `str` in the question is not a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

You can do both replacement in single replace call:

```
var repl = str.replace(/"(\{)|(\})"/g, '$1$2');
```

- Make sure str is a valid string
- You can use built-in JSON parsing to avoid use of regex

Comment: What does ´$1´ and ´$2´ represent?

Comment: They are back reference for the captured matches. One of them will be empty in this case. So `$1` will be `{` and `$2` will be `""` OR `$1` will be `""` and `$2` will be `}`